# how do you specify multiple keywords in the subject filter in MS flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, ms-flow

how do you specify multiple keywords in the subject filter in MS flow?
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you need to retrieve the multiple events who has subject either `MSFlow Test` **OR** `MSFlow Test2` (Correct me if I am wrong).

In that case you need to change your query as given below:

```
subject eq 'MSFlow Test' or subject eq 'MSFlow Test2'
```

Refer below article to know more about how to use filter expressions:

[Using Filter Expressions in OData URIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2016/hh169248(v=nav.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

To specify multiple keywords in the filter in MS flow, you could change:

`subject eq ‘MSFlow Test’ && ‘MSFlow Test2’`

To

`subject eq ‘MSFlow Test’ and subject eq ‘MSFlow Test2’`

Then, I suggest you could use filter query below in your scenario.

`subject eq ‘MSFlow Test’ or subject eq ‘MSFlow Test2’`